# Using words "not" and "until" in the same sentence

Tags: american-english, questions, spoken-english, negation

For example, let's say someone said to me, "You did **not** need to wait **until** I was in the pool to hold me".

I believe this can translate to something like, "You did not need to wait to hold me while I was not in the pool". But what about when the person gets in the pool? Supposing I did held them before they got in, do I continue holding them in the pool or let go (based on the definition of until, meaning up to the point mentioned)?

Comment: Your rephrasing "You did not need to wait to hold me while I was not in the pool" is syntactically valid, but it's "awkward", so it's unlikely any native speaker would ever have said those words.

Comment: Are you asking about the meaning of your first example sentence?

Answer (score 1):

Your original sentence roughly means:

> You waited until I was in the pool before you held me. Waiting was unnecessary.

The function of this sentence is probably:

> Please start holding me before I get into the pool next time I get in.

The time clause "until I was in the pool" only includes the time up to getting in the pool. It says nothing about the time after. *Pragmatically*, it probably means you continue to hold them, but there's nothing in the grammar that requires it.

Comment: Let's say I took my friend to the pool and it's her first time swimming. When we both get in the water, she says, "It's terrifying". Then I reply with, "Want me to hold you?". Then she finally says, "You did not need to wait until I was in the pool to hold me". In this context, would the meaning change for one or both of your interpretations?

Comment: @Max Am I right that she's flirting with him by asking him to hold her, and saying she would have liked it even before she got in?

Comment: The context is based on a video game, made to be safe for work. Neither of them brought up about holding her until they both got in the pool and he asked her first.

Comment: @Max This sounds like a different question to your original one, which I think my answer addresses. What do you actually want to know?

Comment: My specific example aside, is there a general rule of thumb when interpreting a sentence with a "not" and "until"?

Comment: @Max Yes, there is. If you understand what "until" means, it's the exact opposite of that. So if something **happens until 10**, it means it started before 10 and stops at 10. But if it **doesn't happen until 10**, that means it only starts happening at 10, not before. Is that what you really wanted to learn by asking this question?

Answer (score 0):

Your sentence can be paraphrased as “You could have begun holding me—and even finished holding me—while I was still outside the pool.”